# Core Data, adding multiple items to Entity in same instance

Tags: xcode, core-data, addition, record

My code sets up it's Entity, Context etc and then saves a record, that all works fine.  Then I want to save a NEW record but the code overwrites the original record.

How can I write more than one item in the same instance?

```
AppDelegate *appdelagate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
context = [appdelagate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *userData = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
            [userData setValue:@"Bob" forKey:@"userCD"];
            [userData setValue:@"Tall" forKey:@"dataCD"];
            // Store in the DB
            [context save:&error];
```

SOME HOW MOVE TO NEXT RECORD

```
    [userData setValue:@"John" forKey:@"userCD"];
    [userData setValue:@"Short" forKey:@"dataCD"];
    // Store in the DB
    [context save:&error];
```

I am thinking I need to release the userData and declare again...  I am also thinking I am missing a great deal and should stop thinking in terms of SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you change the attributes of the first `userData` object instead of
creating a new one:

```
NSManagedObject *userData;
// Create first object:
userData = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
[userData setValue:@"Bob" forKey:@"userCD"];
[userData setValue:@"Tall" forKey:@"dataCD"];
[context save:&error];
// [userData release];  only if you don't compile with ARC

// Create second object:
userData = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
[userData setValue:@"John" forKey:@"userCD"];
[userData setValue:@"Short" forKey:@"dataCD"];
[context save:&error];
// [userData release];  only if you don't compile with ARC
```

Comment: same up way can do if i have 15 data ?